# Get Location of Value in Nested Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, mapping

I'm working with a rather large and inconsistent dictionary, but for examples sake lets say I've got

```
d = {'a' : 
        {'b' : 
            {'c' : 
                {'one'  :  1}, 
            'd' : 
                {'two' : 2}}

        },
    'e' :
        {'three' : 3},
    'four' : 4

    }
```

I'm trying to find a way to get the locations of the integers. By that I mean `1` would be `['one', 'c', 'b', 'a']`,`2` would be `['two', 'd', 'b', 'a`]` etc...

For the life of me I can't figure this out. I'd rather not create a *location* dictionary (`{1 : ['one', 'c', 'b', 'a'], 2 : ['two', 'd', 'b', 'a`]}`) but instead I'd want to search for one value and then return it's relative location. This is because the actual dictionary I'm working with is very large (several megabytes).

Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: In the case where there are multiple `1`, are you trying to find the first occurrence or all?

Comment: There aren't multiple `1`'s, the values are completely unique. In the actual dictionary, they're large lists. I just made the example integers to simplify the question.

Comment: Well if the actual values are lists then you wouldn't be able to create a location dictionary with the list as the key. Is there something about the path you need to check for? Did you want to match the list exactly? If so then why would you need a location path if you have the list, otherwise were you trying for partial match?

Answer (score 0):

> but instead I'd want to search for one value and then return it's
>   relative location

You can implement a [Breadth-first_search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or Depth-first search algorithm to search the value.